# Жесткая привязка контента к фону

Tags: html, css

Необходимо сделать верстку с background-size: cover или 100% (то есть, фон не масштабируется и занимает всю доступную площадь). Однако фон - это композиция, и имеет значение расположение контента относительно него. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как привязать контент к фону, чтобы при уменьшении/растяжке экрана контент не "уползал" вверх/вниз. К примеру, необходимо, чтобы на облачке внизу располагалась контактная форма. Однако при уменьшении окна она и все остальное "улетает" вверх и все плывет. А хотелось бы. чтобы контент масштабировался в пределах определенной области на фоне - того же облачка, никуда с нее не "уходя".

[image: При масштабе 100%]

[image: 75%, уползло...]

```css
body {
 background: 
 
 url(images/rocks.png) no-repeat,
 url(images/footer.png) no-repeat,
 url(images/form.png) no-repeat,
 url(images/stars_big.png) no-repeat,
 url(images/rocket.png) no-repeat,
 url(images/meteors.png) no-repeat,
 url(images/spaceman.png) no-repeat,
 url(images/background.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Tr2n'; 
    src: url(fonts/Tr2n.ttf); 
   }

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Rotonda bold'; 
    src: url(fonts/Rotonda_bold.ttf);
}   

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.info a:visited, a:link {
 color: #abd2e1;
}

h1, .menu, .info, .contact {
 position: absolute;
}

 h1 {
  font-family: 'Tr2n';
  color: #108ecf;
  font-size: 6.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;  
  left: 28rem;
  top: 25rem;
 }  

 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
 }

 .menu {
  font-family: 'Rotonda bold';
  color: #fe5721;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 .menu-lang {
  left: 70rem;
  top: 2.5rem;
 }

 .menu-nav {
  left: 34rem;
  top: 40rem;
 }

 .menu a {
  color: #fe5721;
 }

 .menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 }

 .menu-lang li {
  padding-left: 0.8rem;
 }

 .menu-nav li {
  padding-left: 2.7rem;
 }

 .menu a:hover {
  color: #abd2e1;
 }

 .info {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #abd2e1;
 }

 .info-top {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-width: 20rem;
  -moz-column-width: 20rem;
  column-width: 20rem;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0.9rem;
  -moz-column-gap: 0.9rem;
  column-gap: 0.9rem;
  width: 50rem;
  left: 37rem;
  top: 49rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

.info a:hover {
 color: #fe5721;
}

 .info-top li {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  line-height: 2.2rem;
 }

 .contact {
  left: 46rem;
  top: 70rem;
 }

 .contact input[type='text'], .contact input[type='email'], #msg {
  width: 17rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #9b9b9b;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border: 1px black solid;
 }

 .contact li {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
 }

#msg {
  height: 9rem;
  
 }

 #address, #map, #phones {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
 }

 #address, #phones {
  margin-left: 8rem;
 }

 .contact input[type='submit'] {
  margin-left: 10rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Rotonda bold' 
 }

 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-indent: 1rem;
 }

 .info-bottom {
  left: 28rem;
  top: 100rem;
  width: 70rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
 }

#links {
 position: absolute;
 top: 110rem;
 left: 52rem;
 margin-bottom: 14rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
<head>
<title> Most Playland </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5">
<meta property="og:title" content="Most Playland">
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<ul class='menu menu-lang'>
<li><a href="#"> UA </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> RU </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> EN </a></li>
</ul> 
<header>
<a href="main.html"><h1> MOST PLAYLAND </h1></a>
</header>
<nav>
<ul class='menu menu-nav'>
<li><a href="#"> О нас </a></li>
<li> <a href="#">Афиша </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Развлечения</a> </li>
<li><a href="#"> Акции </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> Контакты </a></li>
</ul> 
</nav>
<section class='info info-top'>

<ul> 
<li>г. Днепропетровск </li>
<li>ул. Глинки, 2, </li>
<li>ТРЦ "Мост-Сити центр", </li>
<li>2-й уровень </li>
<li>ежедневно с 10:00 - 22:00 </li>
</ul>



<ul>
<li><a href="tel:+380977949426">097-794-94-26,</a> </li>
<li><a href="tel:+380667949426">066-794-94-26,</a></li>
<li><a href="tel:+380567320017">056-732-00-17 </a></li>
<li><a href="mailto:most.playland@mail.ru">most.playland@mail.ru</a> </li>
</ul>


</section>

<form class='contact'>
<ul>
<li><input type='text' placeholder='Имя'> </li>
<li><input type='email' placeholder='E-mail'> </li>
<li><input type='text' placeholder='Сообщение' id='msg'> </li>
<li><input type='submit' value='Отправить'> </li>
</ul>
</form>

<footer class='info info-bottom'>

<ul id='map'> 
<li> <a href="#">О нас</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Афиша</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Развлечения </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Акции </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Контакты </a></li>
</ul>



<ul id='address'> 
<li>г. Днепропетровск </li>
<li>ул. Глинки, 2, </li>
<li>ТРЦ "Мост-Сити центр", </li>
<li>2-й уровень </li>
</ul>



<ul id='phones'>
<li><a href="tel:+380977949426">097-794-94-26,</a> </li>
<li><a href="tel:+380667949426">066-794-94-26,</a> </li>
<li><a href="tel:+380567320017">056-732-00-17 </a></li>
<li><a href="mailto:most.playland@mail.ru">most.playland@mail.ru</a></li> 
</ul>

</footer>
<div id='links'>
<img src="images/face.png" alt='facebook'>
<img src="images/inst.png" alt='instagram'>
<img src="images/yout.png" alt='youtube'>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Поделитесь кодом и мы поможем доработать. Стили и html

Comment: добавил код. Как исправить ситуацию я без понятия, тут мне скрывать нечего. Опыт пока невелик, в основном верстал резиновые макеты в несколько колонок. С таким столкнулся впервые. Даже нагуглить ничего не смог.

Comment: Код ничего не решил ). То, что Вы привели - не ресайзится и фона на горизонте не видно.
Правильнее вопрос звучал бы так "как привязать фон к контенту".
"Однако фон - это композиция, и имеет значение расположение контента относительно него" - для формы он имеет значение? - значит делайте обертку для формы, задавайте ей этот фон. background-size: cover; или background-size: 100%; + max-width: xx px; width: 100%; - для формы.